# Empty URL in cache_invalidate log entires

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I'm monitoring the debug.log file to see when the cache for specific products get invalidated and I see frequent entries like this:

```
main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product_3971","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false}
```

The url is always "http:/". What does that mean? The invalidation wasn't initiated by any http request? If not then what?

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this. The question is "where do the requests that produce these log entries come from?" the answer is cron jobs. I discovered this by adding debug trace code to makeParams function that Dominic shared.

Btw, I answered the question myself but my answer was deleted and downvoted by a reviewer for no good reason. I disputed it but got no response after 6 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url in the cache_invalidate message indicates where the request came from that caused the invalidation. If the value is "http:/", in my experience, this indicates the invalidation originated from a Magento cron job. ie. `php bin/magento cron:run`

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at this before

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Cache/InvalidateLogger.php#L59

```
private function makeParams($invalidateInfo)
    {
        $method = $this->request->getMethod();
        $url = $this->request->getUriString();
        return compact('method', 'url', 'invalidateInfo');
    }
```

So its basically the url variable

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Which means you are getting this returned by the getUriString method

Magento is zend based https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.http.request.html

getUriString()

Return the URI for this request object as a string.

Returns string

As for why yours is incomplete. I dont know.